# How to properly aggregate JS object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asynchronous

I seem to have come across some inconsistent behavior when aggregating object property values after a service call.

```
function(someService) {
  var object = {
    property: 50
  };

  someService.getObject("parameter").then(function(data) {
    //Check value before aggregation
    console.log(object.property);
    console.log(data.property);
    object.property += data.property;
    //Check value after aggregation
    console.log(object.property);
  });

};
```

Assuming that the value of `data.property` is always `50`, the value of `object.property` after the code executes is inconsistent each time the page loads:

Test 1:

Before:
`object.property = 50`, `data.property = 50`
After:
`object.property = 50`

Test 2:

Before:
`object.property = 50`, `data.property = 50`
After:
`object.property = 100`

Test 3:

Before:
`object.property = 50`, `data.property = 50`
After:
`object.property = 100`

Test 4:

Before:
`object.property = 50`, `data.property = 50`
After:
`object.property = 50`

Is there a better way of aggregating these values so that the results are consistent every time?

Comment: Can you show how you're testing the value of `object.property`?

Comment: Are you getting the 'final' value of `object.property` inside the `.then()` function or outside?

Comment: Right now, I'm just logging the object to the console and examining the object's contents using Chrome dev tools.

Comment: I'm logging the values within the `.then()` function

Answer (score 0):

Since I see that you have `then()` in your code which is Promise related function [Promise then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) I assume that your `getObject()` is asynchronous call. The reason you get different results because your console.log or whatever sometimes executed BEFORE asynchronous function `getObject()` is complete and sometimes AFTER. That is why you get inconsistent results. In order to solve this you need to understand asynchronous calls and how to handle them. More importantly you need to check the value of your `object` in your tests AFTER async function is complete.

Let me guess if you use this console.log:

```
someService.getObject("parameter").then(function(data) {
  object.property += data.property;

  console.log(object.property); // always gives you result 100 you expect
});
```

It will show you a proper value `100` all the time.

To convert your function into proper async you can do the following:

```
function myFunc(someService) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var object = {
      property: 50
    };

    someService
      .getObject("parameter")
      .then(function(data) {
        object.property += data.property;

        resolve(object);
      })
      .catch(reject);
    });
  });
};

// somewhere in your tests

myFunc(someService)
  .then(function(object) {
    // do my tests here

    expect(object.property).to.equal(someValue);
  });
```

Comment: Actually, I'm console logging within the `.then()` function before and after the aggregation, so I don't think that it is because the service call has not completed. I will edit my question to better reflect this.

Comment: Then also log what `getObject()` returns as well. Maybe this function returns you inconsistent results.

Comment: I log that as well and it is always consistent (even when the results of the aggregation are not).

Comment: Try to run just one test and see if values are correct. For one execution it should be a proper value. Maybe multiple test executions have an impact on the result

Comment: I have tried that. But the inconsistency that I'm seeing is the result of the aggregation after the page loads. Sometimes it is 100 (which I want), sometimes it is 50. I would think that reloading the page several times should not impact the result of a simple aggregation.